# How to do cumulative sum on lagged values in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have come across problem of creating lagged variables, and especially their cumulative sums in python.

Lets say we have:

```
s=pd.DataFrame({'a':[5,4,3,2,1], 'b':[50,40,30,20,10]},index=[1,2,3,4,5])
```

How can I create lagged cumulative sum of say, 2 rows?
So that, new columns would contain couple NaNs at the beginning and lagged values later? a=[Nan, Nan, 9, 7, 5], b=[Nan, nan, 90, 70, 50]

I was strugling with this thing for the last 4 hours, I am quite new to python, any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

et voila!

```
s.rolling(window = 2).sum()
```

you can further shift / lag your input vector to get different starting points.

```
s.shift(1).rolling(window = 2).sum()
```